# Is there a way using a bash script to get the location of changes made in last git commit?

Tags: shell-script, git

I need to check the location of the files, which were changed in the last commit. Because I will have to do this on Jenkins, this should be done using a bash script. This is the output of `git whatchanged -n 1` (the command I want to use for this)

```
lukas @ leaf (~/workspace/shairweb)   git whatchanged -n 1
commit b4818eca9252c4a218cafefdf99540e4ebfd306d
Author: Lukas Fülling <lukas@mailprovider.com>
Date:   Tue Nov 18 13:13:43 2014 +0100

    Initial release

:000000 100644 0000000... bfa384f... A  pom.xml
:000000 100644 0000000... 370e9a1... A  shairweb.iml
:000000 100644 0000000... 5e513a6... A  src/main/java/net/k40s/shairplay/APIResource.java
:000000 100644 0000000... 45f03cb... A  src/main/java/net/k40s/shairplay/FileParser.java
:000000 100644 0000000... 82aab5b... A  src/main/java/net/k40s/shairplay/Main.java
:000000 100644 0000000... 20d5340... A  src/test/java/net/k40s/shairplay/APIResourceTest.java
```

I tried doing this using `grep` but I believe there is a better way for doing this. How else can I parse it to get something like:

```
src/test/java/net/k40s/shairplay/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
LASTCOMMIT=$(git log -1 --oneline | cut -f1 -d" ")
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $LASTCOMMIT
```

Comment: What about simply using `HEAD` in place of `$LASTCOMMIT`?